# Facebook Authentication using AngularDart

Tags: dart, facebook-authentication

Does anybody have already implemented a Facebook authentication using AngularDart? I know this post: [Dart login/logout example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15498107/dart-login-logout-example) but I stuck with the routing for the Facebook callback-Url. Do you have any example for me? Or do you think it is better to make it serverside e.g. using Node.js Passport?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This looks to be a solid example. Really, it is a better answer for your question than the original question:
[Dart login/logout example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15498107/dart-login-logout-example)

Sadly, it doesn't appear a pre-baked package exists yet. However, for google oauth:
https://github.com/dart-gde/dart-google-oauth2-library